# How to enable Chess 3D on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

The 3D cannot be easily enabled.  A thread that people refer to is

> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=416660

but I tried several suggestions on that thread and it doesn't work yet.

The message is:

> No Python OpenGL support
>   No Python GTKGLExt support

Comment: Yeah I want an answer to this too, I have installed both mentioned packages and it goes to a black screen and just crashes.

Comment: sudo apt-get install python python-q4 might take care of the openGL

Comment: Chess rocks. Not the video game, I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo aptitude install python-opengl python-gtkglext1
```

However I think 3D mode is ugly as well.

Comment: what video card do you have. with mine, it looks nice.

Comment: when i installed the ktkglext1 package, chess wouldn't start any more

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked with just installing the 2 commands, I believe if that does not work it must be your video card. I have to agree the models in 3D look uglier than 2d. I think someone could have spent a little more time in the decoration department. :P